# Google Earth Engine: How to Refresh a GEE App

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to reset a GEE App to its initial state. That includes removing the added Layers and geometries and clear the user entered values (textboxes,...). The App has a Map and Panel with some widgets. Basically I'm looking for the same behavior as refreshing the web-browser.
I tried to add a `ui.Button` as follow:

```
var refreshButton = ui.Button({
  label: 'Reset App!',
  onClick: function() {
  //what to put here??
  }
});
```

I tried the `Map.clear()` and `Panel.clear()`but that is not the behavior I need. 
Any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var oldMap = ui.root.widgets().get(0)

ui.root.clear()
var newMap = ui.Map()
ui.root.add(newMap)

newMap.add(ui.Button('Reset', function () {
  ui.root.clear()
  ui.root.add(oldMap)
}))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/737f135b65d72a24089ea51cdd1c4d19

Comment: Hi Daniel, how should be the code for only refreshing the app at the initial stage? Thanks!